# yii users is duplicating

Tags: php, yii

Users is duplicating every time i create a new users it always comes to `echo $retMessage = "userID already exist.";`help me guys, thank you in advance

**Users::model**

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('userID', 'required'),
        // array('userID', 'unique'),
        array('year, cellphone', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('userID', 'length', 'max'=>15),
        array('password, lastname, firstname, middlename', 'length', 'max'=>45),
        array('course', 'length', 'max'=>10),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('userID, password, lastname, firstname, middlename, course, year, cellphone', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'Authitem'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Authitem', array('name' => 'id')),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'userID' => 'User',
        'password' => 'Password',
        'lastname' => 'Lastname',
        'firstname' => 'Firstname',
        'middlename' => 'Middlename',
        'course' => 'Course',
        'year' => 'Year',
        'cellphone' => 'Cellphone',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('userID',$this->userID,true);
    $criteria->compare('password',$this->password,true);
    $criteria->compare('lastname',$this->lastname,true);
    $criteria->compare('firstname',$this->firstname,true);
    $criteria->compare('middlename',$this->middlename,true);
    $criteria->compare('course',$this->course,true);
    $criteria->compare('year',$this->year);
    $criteria->compare('cellphone',$this->cellphone);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Users the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
```

}

**Maintenance::Controller**

```
    public function actionStudentmaintenance()
{
    $model=new Users('search');
    $this->render('studentmaintenance',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}



public function actionCreateStudent()
{   
    $retVal="";
    $retMessage="";
    $model = new Users('search');
    if(isset($_POST['Users']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Users'];
        $model->role = $_POST['Users']['role'];
        if($model->userID != '' && $model->password != '' && $model->role != '')
            {
                $check_user =  Users::model()->findByAttributes(array('userID'=>$model->userID));
                if(isset($check_user))
                {
                    echo $retMessage = "userID already exist.";
                    die;
                }
                else
                {
                    if($model->save())
                    {
                        $new_role = new Authassignment();
                        {
                            $new_role->itemname = $model->role;
                            $new_role->userID = $model->id;
                            if($new_role->save())
                            {
                                $retVal = "alert-success";
                                $retMessage = "Successfully Saved.";
                            }   
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        else
        {
            echo $retVal = "alert-error";
            echo $retMessage = "Please fill up the form.";
        }       
    }
    $model->unsetAttributes();
    $this->render('studentmaintenance',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it may be possible due to that you defind `UserID` as `primary key` but forget to define it as `Autoincrement` or please show your `db structure`